# Android ContextWrapper fileList() doesnt see my files

Tags: java, android

I have an xml file in res/raw folder, and I want to use it in my app. Why does fileList() not see it while I'm debuging on real device?

Answer (score 2):

`ContextWrapper`'s `fileList()` doesn't return the content of res/raw but the file you stored in the context's application package, E.g (`/data/data/your.app/`). To retrieve the content of res/raw you can use reflection. E.g.

```
public ArrayList<String> listRaw() {
   ArrayList<String> raw = new ArrayList<>();
   Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
   for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
       raw.add(fields[i].getName());
   }
   return raw;
}
```

it will return a `List<String>` with the content of `res/raw`. If you want to get the id you can use

```
getResoruces().getIndentifier(name, "raw", getPackageName());
```

Edit, to copy the file

```
private void copyFile () {
   InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myresource);
   FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
   int read = 0;

   try {
     while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
         out.write(buff, 0, read);
     }
   } finally {
       in.close();
       out.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! And how I can to put mu xml in /data/data/your.app/?

Comment: you have to copy it.  I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: I edited my answer. Change it accordingly to your requirements